# localhost redirected you too many times in NodeJS and Express-session

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, express-session

i am following the tutorial on youtube the code is working fine on his computer but not running on my system.

i am getting error.
"This page isn't working at the momentlocalhost redirected you too many times.
To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies."
the '/' page is working fine when i have try to jump on /home page it doesn't work can anyone help where is the mistake actually? i have followed the tutorial and rewrite the code 5 times unfortunately every time i am getting the same error which is unexpected

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');



const TWO_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2

const {
    PORT = 3000,
    NODE_ENV = 'development',

    SESS_NAME = 'sid',
    SESS_SECRET = 'SADFSDF@*9SDF',
    SESS_LIFETIME = TWO_HOUR
} = process.env

const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production'



const users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Asad', email: 'asad_gmail.com', password: '123'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Abdullah', email: 'abdullah_gmail.com', password: '123'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Shehroz', email: 'shehroz_gmail.com', password: '123'}
]

const app = express();


 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
 }))
 
 

app.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie:{
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: true, 
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))

const redirectLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.session.userId){
        res.redirect('/login')
    } else{
        next()
    }
}

const redirectHome = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.session.userId){
        res.redirect('/home')
    } else{
        next()
    }
}


  
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const {userId} = req.session
    //const userId = 1
    
    res.send(`
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        ${userId ? `

        <a href='/home'>home</a>
        <form method='post' action='/logout'>
        <button>Logout</button>
        </form>

        ` : `
        <a href='/login'>Login</a>
        <a href='/register'>Register</a>
        `}

        

       
    `)
})

app.get('/home', redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a href='/'>Main</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Name:</li>
            <li>Email:</li>
        </ul>
    `)
})

app.get('/login', redirectHome, (req, res) => {
   
   res.send(`
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form method='post' action='/login'>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' required />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' required />
    <input type='submit' />

    </form>
    <a href='/register'>Register</a>
   `)
})

app.get('/register', redirectHome, (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <form method='post' action='/register'>
    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='name' required />
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' required />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' required />
    <input type='submit' />

    </form>
    <a href='/login'>Login</a>
   `)
})

app.post('/login', redirectHome, (req, res) => {
    const {email, password } = req.body

    if(email && password) {
        const user = users.find(user => user.email === email && user.password === password)
    if(user) {
        req.session.userId = user.id
        return res.redirect('/home')
    }
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
})

app.post('/register', redirectHome, (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password } = req.body

    if(name && email && password) {
        const exists = users.some(
            user => user.email === email
        )
        if(!exists) {
            const user = {
                id: users.length + 1,
                name,
                email,
                password
            }
            users.push(user)
            req.session.userId = user.id

            return res.redirect('/home')
        }
    }
    res.redirect('/register')
})

app.post('/logout', redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy(err => {
        if(err){
            return res.redirect('/home')
        }
        res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME)
        res.redirect('/login')
    })
})


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(
    `http://localhost:${PORT}`
))

// npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a loop redirection path. If you try `consolelog("Textsomething")` at `redirectHome` and `redirectLogin` `if` statement, you will find a redirect loop.

One solution is to modify the logic of the redirection function, you can delete the exclamation point in the `redirectHome` `if` statement because it requires a user ID before the / home page can be accessed, etc.